# Unable to Unmarshall to types.Struct with Protobuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, unmarshalling, proto

I am working on a legacy Go app that it's driving me crazy in terms of type definition.

At some point I need to return a value with the value `types.Struct` (from `github.com/gogo/protobuf/types`).

Here is the signature for the function:

```
GetDeviceConfig(ctx context.Context, in *DeviceID, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*types.Struct, error)
```

I'm getting the value from a Postgres database (with GORM) using a string column called "config". It could be any type of JSON.

Just an example:

```
{"fields":{"A":{"Kind":{"string_value":"B"}},"C":{"Kind":{"string_value":"D"}}}}
```

When I try to unmarshall to a `map[string]interface{}` it works like a charm:

```
err := client.DB.Where("id = ?", id, 0).First(&device).Error
    if err != nil && err != gorm.ErrRecordNotFound {
        return nil, err
    }

    var dat map[string]interface{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(device.Config), &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

but I need to conver it to `types.Struct` (valid protobuf signature that cannot be changed). My best guess was something like this:

```
// convert json to struct
    s := types.Struct{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(device.Config), &s); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // fmt.Println(s)
```

but `s` is empty. No data is populated.

Any help?

Comment: What is `types.Struct`? Are you trying to use the type from [`go/types`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/types#Struct)?

Comment: Assuming you use go/types, what are you trying to achieve here? `types.Struct` represents a struct and not an instance of a struct. Your json data also includes values, so what do you expect go to do here?

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear enough `types.Struct` comes from ` `"github.com/gogo/protobuf/types"`

Answer (score 1):

In order to unmarshal JSON into a [Struct](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gogo/protobuf/types#Struct), you need to use [Unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gogo/protobuf/jsonpb#Unmarshaler) found in the [jsonpb](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gogo/protobuf/jsonpb#Unmarshaler) package. Something along the following lines should work:

```
err := jsonpb.UnmarshalString(device.Config, &s)
[...]
```

You can find further examples in [jsonpb_test.go](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/blob/master/jsonpb/jsonpb_test.go).

Comment: Thank you for this. I have spent days looking for this exact thing.